# How to move the templates and configs from sandbox to production docusign account?

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I how do we move our sandbox configs to production like template and object config? I know we have to get our integration key signed to our production but how do we move templates and config?

Answer (score 1):

- Templates need to be migrated manually. You will want to export them from your DEMO account and then import them to your PROD account. Please review the templates afterwards as a sanity check to ensure expected alignment of all tags.
- Account configuration items are also updated manually. If you notice that there are missing configuration options, please contact DocuSign support so they can enable appropriate features if necessary.

Comment: can you elaborate the process of importing templates? According to this 
 [guide](https://sasit.rutgers.edu/how-to-guides/docusign/docusign-documentation-details/220-manage-docusign-templates/872-transfer-template-from-demo-to-production) there is a "New" yellow button. But I see only "Create template" yellow button